# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
def text_objects(text, color, size="small"):
    smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 26)
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)

def screen_message(msg, color, y_displace=0):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color)
    textRect.center = (int(display_width / 2), int(display_height / 2) + y_displace)
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

This is the part of codes that I have an error

Error says,

> line 74, in game_intro screen_message("Welcome to Titans!", white, -100)

which is `screen_message("Welcome to Titans!", white, -100)`

> line 52, in screen_message textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color)
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I do not understand the error why it is talking about NoneType

Comment: May be you should update your question with `text_objects` definition.

Comment: Your `text_objects` method returns `None`, That is why you are getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Comment: A function that doesn't have a `return` statement automatically returns `None`. Whatever you wanted it to return instead, you have to tell Python that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your **text_objects** function has no return statement inside, whereas you assign its return value into textSurf, textRect in the first line of **screen_message** function.

You should ensure that your **text_objects** returns that value pairs in any case. Sometimes people places some if statements for checks before return statements but forget else situations etc. Functions calls which is used as right hand value of an assignment with missing return statements inside can generate this **TypeError("'NoneType' object is not iterable",)** error.